# How to avoid text overflowing in Text widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

i have a Text widget in my app and the text overflow to the right side. i want it to overflow wrap as in CSS.

[image: here is the image]

here is the code

```
 Text('Lorem Ipsum google is the best search engine and youtube is the best video streaming platform.',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF3333333),
                      fontSize: 12,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
```

i tried OveflowBox, Fitted box and tried adding `overflow` and `maxline` properties of Text Widget and none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `Text` with `Expanded` and `Row`. When you don't wrap it with `Expanded`, the `Text` tries to take up as much space as it needs, and if that exceeds the available space, it can lead to overflow issues. By wrapping it with `Expanded` inside a `Row`, you're telling Flutter to allocate the remaining space to `Text` widget.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        'Lorem Ipsum google is the best search engine and youtube is the best video streaming platform.',
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Color(0xFF3333333),
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: The thing is. do we really have to add 2 more widgets just to make this happen? there must be a simpler way right?